# Quiescent power of BJT vs MOS transistors

Tags: mosfet, bjt

This is a question about the power necessary to control a transistor circuit, i.e. the base current in BJTs vs. the gate current in MOSFETs.

Why is there quiescent power dissipated by base currents of BJT's?

Why doesn't it happen with MOSFETS?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question (I doubt anyone can in its current form), but you know that MOSFETS have virtually zero 'base' (gate) current? Hence it can't dissipate any power by virtue of not existing...

Comment: I know mosfets draw almost zero current while idle, my doubt is, can't same thing is possible with BJT's ??

Comment: I am looking for a qualitative comparison and answer/solution here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'idle'? A MOSFET draws (almost) zero gate current, both in on and off states. A BJT with zero gate current is off, gate current is what turns it on.

Comment: There is some power drawn by BJT's even when the circuit is not switching, comparatively, i mean to say, mosfet's offer the advantage that they draw almost zero current while idle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to the answer is buried in the long name of the MOSFET, which is Metal Oxide Semiconductor Field Effect Transistor.

The oxide layer isolates the gate from the channel (drain-source). For the MOSFET to be controlled, you apply a voltage between gate and source, but because of the isolation, the voltage cannot cause a current to flow from gate to source. Gate currents become significant only when you change the voltage, i.e. when you put more charge into the gate or you withdraw charge from the gate. The resistace being formed between drain and gate depends on the field created by the nearby gate, i.e. the gate voltage. Thus, MOSFETs are essentially voltage-controlled devices, not current controlled devices.

A BJT will allow (and require) current to flow into the base when you apply a voltage between the base and the emitter. This current controls the current  from the collector to the emitter. Even if you don't care about the "transistor action", the base-to-emitter part will act like a diode, i.e. it will allow current to flow if biased the right way. One can say that BJTs are current-controlled devices more than they are voltage controlled devices, although you first need a voltage as the cause for the current to flow. Now... Current alone still doesn't explain the power (current * voltage) dissipated by the BJT. Just like with diodes, there is a voltage drop (approx. 0.7 V) across the B-E part of the BJT. Multiply your base current with this "diode drop", and you have a power dissipated by the base current.

This explanation is quite short and by far doesn't cover everything, but it gives you at least some ideas where to start digging further.

However, your question makes sense only when looking at either transistor in the context of a whole circuit. One npn BJT alone can be off with no base and no collector current, so there is no quiescent current. Consider a larger logic circuit in RTL (resistor-transistor logic) vs. CMOS (complementary MOS) logic. With RTL, there will always be some transistors that conduct and some that don't, so some will dissipate power and some won't, even if the circuit "does nothing", i.e. doesn't change its state. CMOS will only require some gate (dis)charge current whenever it changes its state.

Something similar is true for MOSFET-based LDOs (voltage regulators) vs. BJT-based LDOs.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't exactly a true statement "i.e. why doesn't it happen with MOSFET's ?".  It is True for logic type circuits, but for analog circuits both types of transistors consume power, and indeed in BiCMOS (the combination of the two) BJT's can be used to get performance at lower power, in some cases.

By restricting the answer to only logic based circuits we can come up with the following:

BJT's essentially operate on currents and the transistor (in a simple model) is a current amplifier.  CMOS's equivalent simple model is that of a voltage controlled current source, with the control gate being a capacitor.

In CMOS circuits, the transistor sources or sinks current onto the control nodes of other transistors "downstream" so the transistors's "current " aspect only sees capacitor loads (other transistors gates).  With a capacitor you only need to flow current to change the voltage on it, either by injecting current onto the node to bring it high , or draining charge off to bring it low.  Once the capacitor is at a given state, the current need not and indeed does stop flowing.

In BJT circuits, you must provide a current (albeit very tiny) to the next down stream transistor in order for the transistor to amplify that current to set it's new state.  It is simply the fact that you always have to supply some current in all states that BJT's consume more power.

To summarize (using simple models):

CMOS flows current on change, BJT flows less current continuously.

Answer (score 2):

If by "quiescent" you mean "off", as in "no drain or collector current desired", then I think you are wrong to think that MOSFETs leak less current than BJTs. BC547's (BJT) datasheet lists the collector current at \$15nA\$. 2N7000 (MOSFET) lists the zero gate voltage drain current as \$1 \mu A\$, about 66 times more.

Answer (score 0):

A BJT amplifies current (\$I_c=I_b \times H_{fe}\$). Both currents flow out of the emitter. \$H_{fe}\$ is the gain (see datasheets). A BJT also has a diode drop between base and emitter, typically \$V_{be} \gt 0.7V\$.

As a result, the driver circuit for a BJT has to supply power \$V_{be} \times I_{b}\$, if \$I_c \gt 0 A\$, even if Ic is constant. In particular for high current BJTs, \$H_{fe}\$ can be low, often less than 10, so they have high power losses. A darlington (two BJTs stacked) will have a higher \$H_{fe}\$, but \$V_{be}\$ at least doubles.

A FET (not just MOSFET) controls resistance in the drain-source path with an electric field generated by voltage \$V_{gs}\$ between gate and source. There is a very large resistance between gate and source, but also a very large capacitance.

If \$V_{gs}\$ is constant, the capacitance does not matter much. You charge it once and then no more current flows. If you only care about quiescent power and have the necessary drive voltage available, a FET is a good choice for switching. However, if at any time you have to switch high frequency signals, the capacitive current can get large.

You asked about quiescent current, but to give you an idea, in projects that I worked on, the cross over where the BJT drive power became less than FET drive power was around 60kHz.

If you are concerned about drive power near the off-state, consider depletion mode FETs. Those conduct with \$V_{gs} = 0\$ and are turned off by applying a voltage.

To get the best of both worlds, one can use IGBTs, which combine FET and BJT, but they cost a lot more and drivers can be tricky once you get into the MW range.

Comment: Not all FETs have high input capacitances. JFETs, for example isolate the gate by a PN junction instead of an oxide layer. 2N3819 has an input capacitance of 8pF maximum. Compare to 2N7000 (MOSFET) at 50pF maximum, and BC547 (BJT) at 9pF _typical_ (not maximum). Of course, 2N3819 is designed as an RF amplifier and can't handle the current these other devices can, but it does show some FETs can have very low input capacitances.